# GraphQL API Protected branch

Tags: graphql, branch, github-api, github-api-v4

I am using a [GITHUB API V3](https://developer.github.com/v3/) in one of my projects now we are migrating to [GraraphQL API V4](https://developer.github.com/v4). I want to list all the branches of the repo and I want to check whether it is a protected branch. In [GITHUB API V3](https://developer.github.com/v3/) it has a [branches](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/) API that will list all the branches along with it is protected key so it was easy to check. Now in GraphQL, I can get all the branches list but I can't check whether the branch is protected or not.

```
   refs(first: 100, refPrefix: "refs/heads/") {
        nodes {
            name
        }
    }
```

Someone could assist with this on how to proceed?

If that could not be achieved by the `refs` then is there a way to list all the protected branches alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the logic to get the protected branch

```
{
    viewer {
        repository(owner: "parithiban", name: "git-slack-bot") {
            branchProtectionRules(first: 5) {
                nodes {
                    pattern
                    requiredApprovingReviewCount
                    matchingRefs(first: 100) {
                        nodes {
                            name
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer does not work, because it's calling `repository()` with an `owner` argument. It's already scoped to the logged-in user, so you get this error:

```
"errors": [
   ...
   "message": "Field 'repository' doesn't accept argument 'owner'"
]
```

Remove the outermost curly-braces and the word `viewer`, and it will work.